Does "als" always introduces a Nebensatz?
In my language course I have learned that "als" introduces a NS.
For e.g: Als ich ein Kind war, hasste ich die Schule.
However, I sometimes find phrases where "als" is used in a Haupsatz
For e.g: Können Sie so tun, als wären wir bei McDonalds?
Can somebody help me out?

Could you please add why you think this was a Hauptsatz and not a Nebensatz?


Als ich ein Kind war, hasste ich die Schule.
Ich hasste die Schule, als ich ein Kind war.

This is both times the conjunction als. It introduces a temporal adverbial clause.

Können Sie so tun als wären wir bei McDonalds?

This on the other hand is the comparison particle als. Notice the missing comma. It compares the thing in front with the thing following. The whole introduction Können Sie so tun is compared with wir wären. That's why it drops in nicely in the main clause at the end.
Let me phrase this as a statement so you can see it easier:

Wir tun so als wären wir bei McDonalds.


Imo your example is as wrong as your explanation. It should be Wir tun so, als wären wir bei Oma. See also this example in Süddeutsche Zeitung.
